# Linux bat file command line arguments:unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

Tags: linux, shell

i am running a bat file in linux as following .

```
java -cp ../lib/qautils.jar:../lib/Log4jWrapper1.2.jar:../lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:../lib/jaa.jar com.pcube.qa.jaa.server.JAAServer -appdir /home/alpha/jaa/bin"
```

but if i run above getting following error:

```
./runjaa.bat: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./runjaa.bat: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Will anyone suggest me , where i am doing mistake.
If i delete " at the end , saying the directiory ,/home/alpha/jaa/bin does not exists.

Comment: And does the directory exist?

Comment: post the complete script

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what you posted is accurate, you have a trailing `"` on that line that doesn't match up with another quotation mark. A quotation mark opens a quoted string, so your shell is looking for the closing quote.

You don't need the quote in this example, so just remove it.

Comment: If i delete " at the end , saying the directiory ,/home/alpha/jaa/bin does not exists.